# How to handle click event from .swf file in Android

Tags: android, flash, android-webview, dom-events

I have one .swf file which contain some button I want to play some .mp3 on click event of that button from Android code. How to handle events coming from .swf to Android or implement it?

[image]

Comment: i am facing the same issue did u get any workaround to this